# ostringstream error with log4cxx and c++11

Tags: c++, c++11, log4cxx

I'm using log4cxx 0.10.0 and I have a problem compiling my software. I created a test program:

```
#include <sstream>
#include <log4cxx/logger.h>

using namespace log4cxx;
using namespace log4cxx::helpers;

LoggerPtr loggerMyMain(Logger::getLogger( "main"));

int main() {
    std::ostringstream s;
    s << "Test";
    LOG4CXX_DEBUG(loggerMyMain, "aaa" << s);

    return 0;
}
```

and I receive error from gcc:

> /usr/include/log4cxx/helpers/messagebuffer.h: In instantiation of
> 'std::basic_ostream&
> log4cxx::helpers::operator<<(log4cxx::helpers::CharMessageBuffer&,
> const V&) [with V = std::__cxx11::basic_ostringstream]':
> ../main.cpp:23:5:   required from here
> /usr/include/log4cxx/helpers/messagebuffer.h:190:44: error: no match
> for 'operator<<' (operand types are 'std::basic_ostream' and
> 'const std::__cxx11::basic_ostringstream')
> return ((std::basic_ostream&) os) << val;
> ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~

Using C++03 standard the error is no more present. I'm using GCC 8.3.1.

Comment: I don't think `std::ostringstream` has `operator<<` overload that takes `std::ostream` as LHS. https://godbolt.org/z/xhaco6feY

Comment: Ok, but using C++03 it works

Comment: But did it *work*? I can think of a reason why it will *compile*, but actually printing out the content is another matter.